# Display different content using different access level

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

i have the following line of code that check at authentication which user is logged in using defined access level stored in `$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']== 'userlevel'`

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] =='j') {?>
            <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle">year4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle">year3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle">year2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle">year1</a></li>
          </ul>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <?php } ?>
```

i only want to extend the the user group to include other group:
Something like : `<?php if ($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] =='j, s, g, h') {?>`
but  it seems not to throw up any error neither is it working.

But for a single group it works, that is:

```
 <?php if ($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] =='j') {?>
            <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle">year4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle">year3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle">year2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle">year1</a></li>
          </ul>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the *or* operator

```
<?php

    if ($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] =='j'
        ||  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] =='s'
        ||  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] =='g'
        ||  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] =='l') {
?>
          (... Your HTML here...)
<?php

    }
```

Also the `else` block is not required if you do not want to put anything in it. Further more, you needn't open and close your `<?php` and `?>` tags for each line.

if you did need your else block, simply having

```
<?php 
    } else {
        // your code here
    }
?>
```

would be sufficient, and  easier to read.

Comment: you have just helped someone who is ready to push the human race forward; your line of code worked amazingly. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `||` (or) operator:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] == 'j' || $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] == 's' || $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] == 'g' || $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] == 'h') {?>
```

Comment: for the sake of an `if` like this I would make a `$` out of `$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']`. Not important but might make things shorter and more readable.

Comment: Agreed it's clearer. But the idea is still the same.

Comment: @daan Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\index.php on line 136

Comment: @Daan i also agreed to yours been correct; Stephen was clearer both idea is based on the OR operator thank ya all